# Sortable bar chart with long x axis labels rotated

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I need to adjust Mike Bostock's sortable bar chart (available [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705)) for long X axis labels. I have rotated them as slightly vertical and the initial result is that they are well separated and under the X axis but when the sorting process begins, they fall back on the axis.
If anyone could help me set the labels in the right place, I would be very happy!

My JSFiddle is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/liostse/78ssqffp/1/) and the JavaScript code is as follows:

```
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(formatPercent);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
data = [{
    letter: "Alongname1",
    frequency: 0.08167
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname2",
    frequency: 0.01492
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname3",
    frequency: 0.0278
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname4",
    frequency: 0.04253
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname5",
    frequency: 0.12702
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname6",
    frequency: 0.02288
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname7",
    frequency: 0.02022
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname8",
    frequency: 0.06094
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname9",
    frequency: 0.06973
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname10",
    frequency: 0.00153
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname11",
    frequency: 0.00747
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname12",
    frequency: 0.04025
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname13",
    frequency: 0.02517
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname14",
    frequency: 0.06749
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname15",
    frequency: 0.07507
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname16",
    frequency: 0.01929
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname17",
    frequency: 0.00098
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname18",
    frequency: 0.05987
  }
];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
});
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency;
})]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("dx", "-.8em")
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65)");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  });
var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);

function change() {
  clearTimeout(sortTimeout);
  // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
  var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked ?
        function(a, b) {
          return b.frequency - a.frequency;
        } :
        function(a, b) {
          return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter);
        })
      .map(function(d) {
        return d.letter;
      }))
    .copy();
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return x0(a.letter) - x0(b.letter);
    });
  var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
    delay = function(d, i) {
      return i * 50;
    };
  transition.selectAll(".bar")
    .delay(delay)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x0(d.letter);
    });
  transition.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("g")
    .delay(delay);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That behaviour is actually expected: when you call the axis again, the axis generator resets the `dx` and `dy` attributes.

You can apply them again after the second call, just as you did in the first one, but you'll notice that the texts will quickly flicker before going to their new positions.

So, an easy alternative, that avoids the flickering, is setting the labels' positions using the `rotate` itself. For instance (hardcoded values):

```
.attr("transform", "rotate(-65 12 32)");
```

Here is the code with that change:

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 60,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);
var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");
var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(formatPercent);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
data = [{
    letter: "Alongname1",
    frequency: 0.08167
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname2",
    frequency: 0.01492
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname3",
    frequency: 0.0278
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname4",
    frequency: 0.04253
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname5",
    frequency: 0.12702
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname6",
    frequency: 0.02288
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname7",
    frequency: 0.02022
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname8",
    frequency: 0.06094
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname9",
    frequency: 0.06973
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname10",
    frequency: 0.00153
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname11",
    frequency: 0.00747
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname12",
    frequency: 0.04025
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname13",
    frequency: 0.02517
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname14",
    frequency: 0.06749
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname15",
    frequency: 0.07507
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname16",
    frequency: 0.01929
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname17",
    frequency: 0.00098
  },
  {
    letter: "Alongname18",
    frequency: 0.05987
  }
];
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.frequency = +d.frequency;
});
x.domain(data.map(function(d) {
  return d.letter;
}));
y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d.frequency;
})]);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis)
  .selectAll("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-65 12 32)");
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Frequency");
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.letter);
  })
  .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.frequency);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.frequency);
  });
var sortTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
  d3.select("input").property("checked", true).each(change);
}, 2000);

function change() {
  clearTimeout(sortTimeout);
  // Copy-on-write since tweens are evaluated after a delay.
  var x0 = x.domain(data.sort(this.checked ?
        function(a, b) {
          return b.frequency - a.frequency;
        } :
        function(a, b) {
          return d3.ascending(a.letter, b.letter);
        })
      .map(function(d) {
        return d.letter;
      }))
    .copy();
  svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .sort(function(a, b) {
      return x0(a.letter) - x0(b.letter);
    });
  var transition = svg.transition().duration(750),
    delay = function(d, i) {
      return i * 50;
    };
  transition.selectAll(".bar")
    .delay(delay)
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return x0(d.letter);
    });
  transition.select(".x.axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("g")
    .delay(delay);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
  fill-opacity: .9;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox"> Sort values</label>
```